# How to take a CSV file and write it to a model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, model

I have a model called '`items`' in rails, and I want to be able to import rows from a CSV file that saves into the items model. I do not want to save the CSV file, only save the rows in the CSV file as different rows in the model.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could easily create a rails task to do this.

```
require 'csv'

desc "Import from csv"
task :csv_import => [:environment] do

  file = "items.csv"

  CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|

    Item.create! do |u|
      u.name = row[0]
    end
  end
end
```

end